# facebook like button not work

Tags: c#, facebook, blogengine.net

My facebook "like" extension does not work properly. It only posts like URLs to walls. But I saw some on some blogs that when I like the post it will show up on my wall with the title and post content, including images. But on my blog it only shows URL. Please help me find the reason. I'm using .net blogengine: see [this](http://www.isharpnote.com/).

Comment: You are not talking about the **old** share button right? can you provide us the *other* blogs that have this special like plugin?

Comment: http://www.spiceupyourblog.com/2010/04/facebook-like-icon-blogger-posts.html
check this and this uses blogger but i have my own domain and using blogengine.net

Comment: @gayancc: So, it's talking about the new Like Plugin? what about it?

Comment: @ifaour i don't know whether it's new plugin or old im using the one which on facebook social site include.

Comment: @gayancc: Can you take a screenshot of the plugin you are talking about? maybe along with its popup?

Comment: @ifaour :this is the plugin that i ahve used http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: And it is the same plugin in the other website?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have [Like button extension](http://dnbegallery.org/cms/List/Extensions/FacebookLike) but really want [Like button widget](http://dnbegallery.org/cms/List/Widgets/FBpageLikeBox).

Comment: no i it'was facebook error first link that you shared i'm the author i have solved the issue